# Using jQuery MiniColors with Aurelia binding

Tags: jquery, aurelia

For some reason the jQuery MiniColors color picker (http://labs.abeautifulsite.net/jquery-minicolors/) seems to not work correctly with Aurelia data binding.

**calendar.html** (template):

```
<!-- src/settings/school/calendars -->
<template>
  <require from="jquery-minicolors/jquery.minicolors.css"></require>
  <form>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label" for="cal_name_orig"><span t="Calendar_name"></span></label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" ref="cal_name_orig" value.bind="calendar.cal_name_orig & validate" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label" for="cal_color"><span t="Color"></span></label>
      <input type="text" id="cal_color" class="form-control" value.bind="calendar.cal_color">
    </div>
  </form>
</template>
```

And my **calendar.js** (view-model)

```
//src/settings/school/calendars.js
import 'jquery-minicolors';

export class SettingsSchoolCalendars {

  error = null;
  selectedId = null;
  calendar = {};

  attached() {
    var self = this;
    // set focus when modal is shown
    $("#cal_color").minicolors({
      control: "wheel",
      theme: "bootstrap",
    });
  }
}
```

The control works in the form, but there are two problems with the binding:

1. The value of calendar.cal_color appears in the input but does NOT set the color of the color picker.
2. When I change the color picker color, the new value appears in the input but does NOT update the binded value calendar.cal_color.

Is jQuery MiniColors messing with the value.bind property of the input control?  Is there another explanation?

I can successfully get the model to update by adding this to the MiniColors instantiation:

```
  change: function(hex, opacity) {
    self.calendar.cal_color = hex;
  }
```

But, I can't seem to do the opposite (update the MiniColors control when the model changes).  And it still doesn't load the initial color correctly.

Help!

Comment: You should not be doing `$("#cal_color")...` You should use the `ref` attribute to obtain a reference on your VM to the element you want to reference. `<input ref="cal_color"...` and then in your VM code `$(this.cal_color)...` Also, you generally don't need to do `var self = this` in ES2015. You can use a fat arrow function to get a properly set up `this`. Though sometimes jQuery type stuff will mess with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't seem to be having issues with this control. I just played with it.

In my HTML, I have this:

```
<input type="text" ref="minicolors" value.bind="color" class="form-control" id="color">
<div>Color: ${color}</div>
```

Then I set a default color:

```
color = '#ff6161';
```

Finally, in my attached callback, I use the ref'd element:

```
attached() {
  $(this.minicolors).minicolors({
    change: (value, opacity) => {
      this.color = value;
    }
  });
}
```

It's all working for me as expected.

Edit:
I finally got around to creating a gist to show this all off: https://gist.run/?id=6e4a6ea77751ae9c69b178eb51105137

**app.html**

```html
<template>
    Control value: ${controlValue}
  <form>
        <div class="form-group">
            <test></test>
            <label for="color">Color</label>
            <input type="text" value.bind="colorInfo.color" class="form-control" id="color">
      <div>Color: ${colorInfo.color}</div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <test></test>
            <label for="color">Color</label>
            <input type="text" ref="minicolors" value.bind="colorInfo.color" class="form-control" id="color">
      <div>Color: ${colorInfo.color}</div>
        </div>
    </form>
</template>
```

**app.js**

```js
import {inject, BindingEngine} from 'aurelia-framework';

@inject(BindingEngine)
export class App {
  colorInfo = {
    color: '#ff6161'
  }

  constructor(bindingEngine) {
    this.subscription = bindingEngine.propertyObserver(this.colorInfo, 'color')
      .subscribe( () => {
        this.widget.minicolors('value', this.colorInfo.color);
      });
  }

  attached() {
    this.widget = $(this.minicolors);
    this.widget.minicolors({
      change: (color, opacity) => {
        this.colorInfo.color = color; 
        this.colorInfo.opacity = opacity;
      } 
    });
  }

  get controlValue() {
    if(this.widget) {
      return this.widget.minicolors('value');
    }
    return '';
  }

  detached() {
    subscription.dispose();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice... I'd been using the ref earlier but switched to an ID handle as part of my troubleshooting.

Comment: However, I still can't get this to work.  The change function works great (thanks also for the help with the fat arrow function to avoid the need of self) and it updates the value.  My main problem is that the minicolors control just won't display the correct color unless I click it and select a color.  Changing the value of this.color updates the textbox (binding is working) but doesn't change the color of the color chooser.

Comment: In the meantime, check out the `@observable` decorator to see the direction I'm going.

Comment: If I put buttons to call these functions, it works:
`goBlue() { $(this.cal_color).minicolors('value', '#0000ff'); }` and `goGreen() { $(this.cal_color).minicolors('value', '#00ff00'); }`

Comment: Check out this gist I wrote yesterday. I think it will point you in the right direction: https://gist.run/?id=268540dfcc55c2c34cf0217490d82046

Comment: You need to use a propertyObserver, set up a callback on the property you have bound the input box to. In the callback, pass the new value to the minicolors instance.

Comment: I've updated the post and added a full example. Check it out!